# Custom Button with 3 NormalState Images objective c

Tags: objective-c

Please help Wanted to make a custom button that when press once it toggles on and off and each of the toggles has different images and when the button is hold for 3 sec, it toggles to a different state and changes to another image. here is my code from .m file:

```
enter code here -(IBAction)custompowerbutton:(id)sender{ UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *holdButton = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(holdButton:)];
    holdButton.minimumPressDuration = 3.0; //seconds
    [btn addGestureRecognizer:holdButton];

if( [[btn imageForState:UIControlStateNormal] isEqual:[UIImage imageNamed:@"offbutton.png"]])
{
    btn.highlighted = YES;
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"onbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightedonbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    label2.text = @"On";

}

if([label2.text  isEqual: @"ignation On"])
    {
 btn.highlighted = YES;
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ignitionbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightedignitionbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; }
else
{
    btn.highlighted = YES;
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"offbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlightedoffbutton.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    label2.text = @"off";
}}- (void)holdButton:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture{if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
{        
    label2.text = @"ignition On";     
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two arrays of images. Create two methods and add them to the button. One method for tapping on button, other for holding her. In first method use `setImage:forState:` method for changing images from 1th array. In second method use `setImage:forState:` method for changing images from 2nd array. Its will be simple.

This sample should help you:

```
[cellOverView addTarget:_____ action:@selector(______) forControlEvents:UIControlEvent________];
```